# Using bitwise operators with large numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript, compression, long-integer

I am writing a Javascript version of this Microsoft [string decoding algorithm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/spatial-data-services/geodata-api) and its failing on large numbers.  This seems to be because of sizing (int / long) issues.  If I step through the code in C# I see that the JS implementation fails on this line

```
n |= (b & 31) << k;
```

This happens when the values are (and the C# result is 240518168576)

```
(39 & 31) << 35
```

If I play around with these values in C# I can replicate the JS issue if `b` is an `int`. And If I set `b` to be `long` it works correctly.

So then I checked the max size of a JS number, and compared it to the C# long `result`

```
240518168576 < Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER = true
```

So.. I can see that there is some kind of number size issue happening but do not know how to force JS to treat this number as a long.

Full JS code:

```
private getPointsFromEncodedString(encodedLine: string): number[][] {

    const EncodingString = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_-";

    var points: number[][] = [];

    if (!encodedLine) {
        return points;
    }

    var index = 0;
    var xsum = 0;
    var ysum = 0;

    while (index < encodedLine.length) {
        var n = 0;
        var k = 0;

        debugger;

        while (true) {
            if (index >= encodedLine.length) {
                return points;
            }

            var b = EncodingString.indexOf(encodedLine[index++]);

            if (b == -1) {
                return points;
            }

            n |= (b & 31) << k;
            k += 5;
            if (b < 32) {
                break;
            }
        }

        var diagonal = ((Math.sqrt(8 * n + 5) - 1) / 2);

        n -= diagonal * (diagonal + 1) / 2;

        var ny = n;
        var nx = diagonal - ny;

        nx = (nx >> 1) ^ -(nx & 1);
        ny = (ny >> 1) ^ -(ny & 1);

        xsum += nx;
        ysum += ny;

        points.push([ysum * 0.000001, xsum * 0.000001]);
    }

    console.log(points);

    return points;
}
```

**Expected input output:**

Encoded string

> qkoo7v4q-lmB0471BiuuNmo30B

Decoded points:

- 35.89431, -110.72522
- 35.89393, -110.72578
- 35.89374, -110.72606
- 35.89337, -110.72662

Comment: Can you click `[<>]` and produce a [mcve] with example input and expected output?

Comment: [BigInts](https://v8.dev/features/bigint) will help you `console.log((1n << 32n).toString())`, but the support is not quite there ..

Comment: While the duplicate explains what's happening, it doesn't really help with resolving the issue.

Comment: I've fixed your code to work with vanilla Javascript (well, Typescript :) - https://jsfiddle.net/Luaan/jrkpgu8d/3/ Should be pretty straight forward, ask away if there's anything unclear.

Comment: @Luaan I really appreciate the effort in your answer, it doesnt work for me unfortunately. I'll update the question with input / output.

Comment: There's something wrong with that input string - even in the C# version, it gives me bogus coordinates. Are you sure you've copied it correctly? Or maybe it's using a different version of the encoding?

Comment: @Luaan Interesting, here is a gist of the C# encoding and decoding code as well as a rudimentary test I used to validate the string you initially used https://gist.github.com/chris-eaton/dead2a828dbbf5c9db3226dd59ee38e5

Comment: Yeah, I think there's definitely some subtle difference with your C# implementation of the encoding - the Javascript version at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/rest-services/elevations/point-compression-algorithm#javascript-implementation gives me the expected `vx1vilihnM6hR7mEl2Q` as result. I think you need to be more careful with where you use integers - in the Javascript version, integers are only used for the bitwise operations, everything else is `double`. Order of operations (namely `*` vs. `/`) might also matter, especially on integers.

Comment: @Luaan Thank you again for your help with this, it really is appreciated. It also seems like I have a bug somewhere! :shrug:

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> **Bitwise operators treat their operands as a sequence of 32 bits**
>   (zeroes and ones), rather than as decimal, hexadecimal, or octal
>   numbers. For example, the decimal number nine has a binary
>   representation of 1001. Bitwise operators perform their operations on
>   such binary representations, but they return standard JavaScript
>   numerical values.

`(39 & 31) << 35` tries to shift 35 bits when there only 32

[Bitwise Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)

To solve this problem you could use [`BigInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) to perform those operations and then downcast it back to `Number`

```
Number((39n & 31n) << 35n)
```

You can try this:

```
function getPointsFromEncodedString(encodedLine) {

    const EncodingString = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789_-";

    var points = [];

    if (!encodedLine) {
        return points;
    }

    var index = 0;
    var xsum = 0;
    var ysum = 0;

    while (index < encodedLine.length) {
        var n = 0n;
        var k = 0n;


        while (true) {
            if (index >= encodedLine.length) {
                return points;
            }

            var b = EncodingString.indexOf(encodedLine[index++]);

            if (b === -1) {
                return points;
            }

            n |= (b & 31n) << k;
            k += 5n;
            if (b < 32n) {
                break;
            }
        }

        var diagonal = ((Math.sqrt(8 * Number(n) + 5) - 1) / 2);

        n -= diagonal * (diagonal + 1) / 2;

        var ny = n;
        var nx = diagonal - ny;

        nx = (nx >> 1) ^ -(nx & 1);
        ny = (ny >> 1) ^ -(ny & 1);

        xsum += Number(nx);
        ysum += Number(ny);

        points.push([ysum * 0.000001, xsum * 0.000001]);
    }

    console.log(points);

    return points;
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for this, is there anyway around it?

Comment: @Chris you can use BigInt `Number((39n & 31n) << 35n)`

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I believe BigInt doesn't work in Edge / IE11 so may have to look at BigInteger instead

Comment: @Chris I do have a solution that uses Javascript numbers, but I can't post it, since the question is closed :P

Comment: @Luaan I voted for reopen